# FSMO and third party time sync

Tags: windows, ntp, domaincontroller

We have configured two new DC in our network and are working to set them up to maintain the lab and production networks. We are using a third part time program (presentense) for NTP (customer insistence), and are trying to set up the DC to use it instead of Windows NTP.

We get an error that the windows time program is not running (disabled) and we want this to track the presentense third party application instead. Can it?

Currently checking case notes and support pages for others who have done this.